# Does reading of a Android Cursor go all the way to the database?

Tags: android, database

I've got a kind of heavy Android application and want to make sure not never ANR it.

I've moved my database queries away from the UI thread (to AsyncTasks), but I still read from the cursor in the ui thread since I suppose the returned cursor is stored somewhere in memory, i.e. the actual reading of it does not go the entire way to the database. Is that correct or do i really need to move all reads of the cursor to non UI threads as well?

To be more specific:

Does for example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int) read from memeory, or does it aquire some kind of read lock from the actual SQLite database.

I guess the Cursor implementation in my case is an SQLiteCursor since the ContentProvider is implemented using an SQLite database.

Answer (score 10):

When you call `query()` or `rawQuery()` on a `SQLiteDatabase`, a `Cursor` is returned immediately, because the actual query itself is delayed until you start using data. Any call that manipulates the `Cursor` or needs data that implies that the query is executed (e.g., `getCount()`) will actually execute the query. Hence, it is best to "touch" the `Cursor` in `doInBackground()` while you are on the background thread.

From that point forward, though, the entire result set is in memory, for result sets under 1MB.

Comment: Well, i don't think the query or rawQuery is asynchronous in the way you describe it, atleast not in an Android environment using ContentProviders. According to my knowledge they are synchronous and will not return until the query is finished. Adding debug timestamps  before and after the query invocation can results in that you have to wait more than 1000 ms for a slow query. I actually think the cursor is hold in memory after that the query has finished, i.e. query moves the result to memory and reading from the cursor (getInt for example) is done in memory.

Comment: @SoftCharles: "atleast not in an Android environment using ContentProviders" -- your question discussed SQLite, not content providers, so I gave you the answer for SQLite, not content providers. I apologize for not answering the question that you did not actually ask.